# Redirect part of URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/7736-3-ideias-para-afinar-a-sua-m%C3%A1quina-de-vender-na-internet.html
```

To:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/artigos/7736-3-ideias-para-afinar-a-sua-m%C3%A1quina-de-vender-na-internet.html
```

That is: replacing the `item` part of the URL.

My code in .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+/item/(.+)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: this is a Joomla 3 site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `item` is start of URL you should be using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^item/(.+)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this rule at start of your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.