# Redirect page and its subelements to a single page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all pages that begin with:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/forum *
```

To:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html
```

No matter if it is:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/forum
```

Or:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/forum/abc...
```

They should all point to:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html/? [R=301,L]
```

And:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**:

These are all other redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.portal-gestao.com
RewriteRule ^gestao/item/(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^component/k2/(.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^itemlist/user/(.*)$ /artigos/author/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ /artigos/tag/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^forum(/|$) /fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html[R]

##Ver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628668/replace-4-digit-in-url-by-text-4-digit Estava com erros 404 (10-11-2015)
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}-.*)$ /item/$1 [R=301,L]

## Redirect para substituir /item por /artigos/ no URL ver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283968/redirect-part-of-url
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^item/(.+)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]

## End - Custom redirects
```

Comment: Your first rule should be working, except for `https://www.portal-gestao.com/forum`. Your second rule should be working as well but won't behave as you expected. **1)** Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled. **2)** Make sure htaccess are allowed (apache config). **3)** if you have other rules in your htaccess, please update your question with the entire file

Comment: Thanks, yes I have mod_rewrite enabled and other custom redirects. I will update the question.

Comment: Had a look at your htaccess. Could you tell me if other rules are working ? Is it only this one that's not working or others too ?

Comment: Yes all other rules are working except this one

Comment: What's the url you're testing ? When you say "not working" you mean nothing happens ? I don't know if it's a typo but you need to add a space between your rule and `[R]` flag

Comment: See for example this page: https://www.portal-gestao.com/forum/eni-registo-comercial-e-firma.html it's not being redirected to https://www.portal-gestao.com/fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum(/|$) /fórum-perguntas-e-respostas.html[R]
```

It should be in your root htaccess of course.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit above. I tried this also, but it isn't working.